# Map file with GCC on OSX

Tags: c++, gcc

I am using GCC on Mac OSX. I am trying to get GCC to create a map(or listing) file of all the symbols in the project so it contains the addresses at which they are mapped.

I read in the GCC manual that a way of generating such map files is to pass system specific flags to the GCC linker using -Xlinker option.

But I cannot find what the option itself is. Does anyone know if this is possible with using GCC on OSX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ld option is `-map`.  With `-Xlinker` you would write:

```
gcc -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /path/to/map ...
```

You can also write this more concisely with `-Wl`:

```
gcc -Wl,-map,/path/to/map ...
```